# LaunchScreen.storyboard & SwiftGif

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, cocoapods

I found a gif I would like to play on my LaunchScreen.storyboard, and since my research supported that Swift 4 didn't natively support playing gifs, I found a CocoaPod named [SwiftGif](https://github.com/swiftgif/SwiftGif) that auto-plays gifs in a UIImageView. With SwiftGif, you have to programmatically assign the gif to the UIImageView.

`let jeremyGif = UIImage.gif(name: "jeremy")`

If you just select the gif from the dropdown of images in the Storyboard, it won't play. The problem is that I can't give the LaunchScreen.storyboard file (or a view inside of it) a custom class, or I will get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRprn.png). What can I do?

I'm using Xcode 9.2, Swift 4, MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports), and macOS High Sierra 10.13.2.

Thank you!

Comment: The launch screen is static. It can't run any code. Period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the launch screen only allows for static images to be placed. Animations or custom code is not allowed. However, you can make the feeling of an animated launch screen by presenting a view with the same image and position as the launch screen and animating the view right after launch.

Answer (score 2):

In order to implement a GIF animation on the launch screen, you'll need to do two things:

1. Add the first frame of the GIF as a static image in the launch screen
2. When the app launches add a view in the root view controller that loads the animated GIF at the same spot that you’ve put the static image in the launch screen

This way, when the app launches the user will get the impression that the launch screen is animating.
You can read a detailed explanation on how to do it [on this blog post](https://www.amerhukic.com/animating-launch-screen-using-gif).
I've also set up [an example project on GitHub](https://github.com/amerhukic/AnimatedGifLaunchScreen-Example) that shows how to implement it using the [SwiftyGif](https://github.com/swiftgif/SwiftGif) pod that you used.